# What's the textbox at up-left corner in a sliderbar?

Tags: java, gwt, slider

I found a hidden small textbox at up-left corner in an instance of SliderBarSimpleHorizontal:

```
<input type="text" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" style="opacity: 0; height: 1px; width: 1px; z-index: -1; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;">
```

Could anyone tell me what kind of hack is this?
 (gwt-slider-bar home: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-slider-bar/)

Comment: Please mention browser and also attach a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way GWT makes widgets focusable in a way that's compatible with Firefox (Firefox supports `tabindex="-1"` on all elements to make them focusable, but doesn't support `accesskey` on elements that are not default-focusable): https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/impl/FocusImplStandard.java

And the slide bars in this project extend `FocusPanel` (which in itself is disputable, as they're not panels).

Answer (score 0):

I just browsed the source code. I see only one use case for texbox and it is in trunk/SliderBarMVP/src/com/kiouri/sliderbar/client/demo/interractive/InrerractiveSample.java

[SliderBarSimpleHorizontal](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-slider-bar/source/search?q=SliderBarSimpleHorizontal%20&origq=SliderBarSimpleHorizontal%20&btnG=Search%20Trunk) has not reference to textbox or input element!!!

You can search through code - http://code.google.com/p/gwt-slider-bar/source/search?q=SliderBarSimpleHorizontal+&origq=SliderBarSimpleHorizontal+&btnG=Search+Trunk